# for-loops and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Trying to relearn python, working with ***Introducing Python*** by Bill Lubanovic. While learning about dictionaries, he uses this `for` loop to reverse the dictionary `e2f` to `f2e`:

```
e2f = {'dog': 'chien', 'cat': 'chat', 'walrus': 'morse'}
f2e = {}
for english, french in e2f.items():
    f2e[french] = english
```

I really don't understand these `for` loops, we never defined `french` or `english`, and I don't know how this process reverses the dictionary. If someone could explain this for loop it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)?

Comment: If this book you're reading is using syntax without explaining it anywhere, you need to find a better book.

Comment: This was a specific case that I didn't understand in the book. I don't think that case was shown on the docs.

Comment: When you do e2f.items(), it unpacks the dictionary and return a list:  [('walrus', 'morse'), ('dog', 'chien'), ('cat', 'chat')]  .  The for loop is just looping through it and assigning the first value  to english, and the second value to french.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!